# question about learning TDD

Tags: java, unit-testing

what are the best books to learn about junit, jmock and testing generally? Currently I'm reading pragmatic unit testing in Java, I'm on chapter 6 its good but it gets complicated.. is there a book for a bottom up? from your experience which helped you get the testing concept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, the best thing that has helped me learn unit testing is reading the many blogs out there.

After that there are books such as [Test Driven Development by Example by Kent Beck](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321146530), [xUnit Test Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131495054), [The Art of Unit Testing](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=Test+Driven+Development&x=0&y=0) etc.

Some books are for java, others for C#...I don't really think it matters which language you read about TDD in as it all helps in one way or another.

Comment: @mezoid thank you , I'm specified in particular books that benefited you, interested in writting unit test in java not other languages, I did already download bunch of books including some from the list but I want to see what is recommended by expirirenced developers..

Answer (score 1):

[Test Driven Developemnt by Kent Beck](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321146530) is the original. Read it's great. But the best way to learn is to practice. Check out different [Katas](http://codingdojo.org/) (exercises) at the dojo site.

Answer (score 0):

[Growing Object-Oriented Software Guided by Tests](http://www.growing-object-oriented-software.com/) is a great title. Contains lots of examples, which is always better than a purely academic talk.

If you have any questions about real life problems or examples from any of your books, just ask a question here.

Comment: @Grzenio thank you I'll have a look of it, I can't really ask questions with my code here since it is corporate property.. Thats why I need to read, code, code and figure it out on my own

Comment: @GandalfStormCrow, the corporate property of the code can be an issue... You can always try to recreate the problem in a sandbox (call classes A, B, etc)